# Routing with Iterating list in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Each list routing shows same routing.So how can i go each item of the list each routes.But routing shows the same path.

```
var names = ['Home', 'About', 'Contact'];
    <Router>
      <div>
    <ul>
                    {names.map(function(name, index){
                        return <li key={ index }><Link to="/">{name}</Link></li>;
                      })}
                </ul>
        <hr/>

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to link to different paths or that you want the name to show up differently?  If you want to link to different paths, you have to change `<Link to="/">{name}</Link>` to something dynamic like ``<Link to={`/${name}`}>{name}</Link>`` because you're hard-coding the link for now.  Another suggestion would be to try an arrow function: ``{names.map((name, index) => (<Link to={`/${name}`}>{name}</Link>)}``

Comment: its works thanks a lot man

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understand is that the link return same path in map. So to get different paths in map try below code

```
render(){
   const names = ['Home', 'About', 'Contact'];
   const nameItems = names.map((name, index) => {
       let url =  "/";
       if( name == "Home"){
           url = "/";
       }else{
           url = name.toLowerCase();
       }
         return <li key={ index }><Link to={url}>{name}</Link></li>;
       })} 
    return(
        <Router>
  <div>
<ul>
               {nameItems}
            </ul>
    <hr/>

    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
  </div>
</Router>
    )
   }
```

Comment: @MD.ALIMUL Alrazy I updated my answer please try now